# htaccess Redirect when 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a subdirectory called `/marker`, in it are some png files. Now I want the file `/marker/standard.png` to be returned whenever an attempt is made to call a png that does not exist. In other words: If, for example, `/marker/doesntexist.png` is called (which doesn't exist), `/marker/standard.png` should be delivered.

Sounds quite simple, but several attempts with `RewriteRule` or `ErrorDocument` failed.

Any ideas?
tia

Comment: You should include what you have tried in your question, together with any existing directives, as it could be a simple error/conflict. After all, this should be a relatively simple rule. There could also be something with regards to your server config that is preventing it from working. If, for instance, you have a front-end caching proxy that serves static assets (not uncommon) then your rule in `.htaccess` might not even be processed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to serve `/marker/standard.png` if another `.png` file in the `/marker` directory is requested that does not exist.

This uses mod_rewrite and should go near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^marker/(?!standard\.png$).+\.png$ marker/standard.png [L]
```

I took the extra step to exclude requests for `standard.png` itself (using a negative lookahead), in case this doesn't exist for some reason.

Note that this is a case-sensitive string comparison. eg. Only `.png` files are matched, not `.PNG`.

This naturally results in a 200 OK response when `standard.png` is served. If you still need a 404 Not Found status then use `ErrorDocument` instead (see the next section).

---

#### Using `ErrorDocument`

You also mentioned the use of an `ErrorDocument` directive. This is another solution, although it will result in a 404 HTTP response status, which may or may not be desirable.

For example, in order to restrict this `ErrorDocument` just to the `/marker` subdirectory then create an additional `.htaccess` file in this subdirectory with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /marker/standard.png
```

This will naturally serve `standard.png` for any non-existent request to the `/marker` subdirectory. To restrict this to `.png` requests only then wrap the `ErrorDocument` in an `<If>` expression. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /\.png$/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /marker/standard.png
</If>
```